# Making div take the "free space" on the right?

Tags: html, css

In the following code, I'm trying to make the Orange `div` (`class="Inner3"`) fit into the top right part of the container div (since there is a free space). Tried it using `float` and played with `display:inline-block` but it didn't work. Can anyone show me how to do it?

Thank you.

```css
.OuterDiv {
  width: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #E3EAD7;
  height: 1000px;
}
.Inner1 {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #6D97C0;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.Inner2 {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #ECB7D8;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.Inner3 {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #F5E6AD;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="OuterDiv">
  <div class="Inner1"></div>
  <div class="Inner2"></div>
  <div class="Inner3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are looking for a way to calculate "ideal fits" of the elements within the width of the `.outerDiv`. You will need some Javascript for that to iterate over all the `.InnerX` elements and find the "best fits per row".

Comment: Want something like this? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ac14ofd/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So what is happening in your case: You have set all three `div` as `float:left` (Which will align them next to each other in single row) and you have put fixed width to their parent(which is not enough for their combined width), That's why two divs came on next line and still attached to each other.

Why don't you remove `float: left` from Inner3 or remove `width` from parent

Comment: It seems to worked once I dropped the "float" and set the wrapper to width:100% and height:100%. can you explain why?. I'm trying to build a responsive web design and trying to find a method to "cover" empty spaces, so I used that technique. thank you.

Comment: It's because when you apply `float:left` to any element,it leaves it's order in page and try to get on top-left of it's parent(if no `top` is mentioned). In your case as all three inner div are `float:left` they try to do same and gets aligned in single row next to each other. But as your wrapper is smaller in width than their combined width, they(inner div) manages them self by going to next line. 

If you want properly responsive page always use width in % also google for `media quries` it will help you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove the **width** and **float** properties from .Inner3 class styles and it will work.

```
.Inner3 {
  background-color: #F5E6AD;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
}
```

See full example below:

```css
.OuterDiv {
  width: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #E3EAD7;
  height: 1000px;
}
.Inner1 {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #6D97C0;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.Inner2 {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #ECB7D8;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.Inner3 {
  background-color: #F5E6AD;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="OuterDiv">
  <div class="Inner1"></div>
  <div class="Inner2"></div>
  <div class="Inner3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the first 2 `Inner` div's in a wrapping div and give that a property of `float: left`.

Please note, the below is far from perfect as I don't know the exact context of what the scenario is (I've converted the static widths to percentages for this example) but gives an indication of what you might be able to do?

```css
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}

.OuterDiv {
  width: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #E3EAD7;
  height: 1000px;
}
.wrap {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}
.Inner1 {
  background-color: #6D97C0;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}
.Inner2 {
  background-color: #ECB7D8;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}
.Inner3 {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #F5E6AD;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="OuterDiv">
  <div class="wrap cf">
    <div class="Inner1"></div>
    <div class="Inner2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="Inner3"></div>
</div>
```

Clearfix source: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/